# multi-language Enable or Disable in SAP FIORI Launchpad

Tags: sapui5

Two language(English and German) are available on SAP Launchpad Login page.

SAP MANUALS, I found that we have to redefine below property :

## Application supported languages

application_languages=EN,DE,FR

But I am not able to find exact place where to make the changes to enable or disable Arabic language.

Can anyone please help on this?

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, launchpad texts are displayed in the logon language. You can override this setting using a URL parameter.

The language for launchpad texts is set according to the following process:

1)  If a value is set for URL parameter sap-language and the specified language is installed on the backend server, launchpad texts are displayed in this language.

2)  If no language is defined for URL parameter sap-language, launchpad texts are displayed in the default language set in the ABAP system in Maintain User Profile (transaction SU01).

3)  If no language is defined for URL parameter sap-language or Maintain User Profile, the browser settings for header field Accept-Language are taken into account. The system selects the first language from the list that is maintained in the browser, and which is also installed in the SAP system.

Please see also the [corresponding docu](https://help.sap.com/viewer/17ae0e97e0fc424a9c368f350c0ba6bd/2.10/en-US/65edb2db3a6b452a97633f0027bf0922.html).